# how to perform XOR of all words in a file

Tags: python, dictionary, cryptography, dictionary-attack

I want to convert all words in a standard dictionary (for example : /usr/share/dict/words of a unix machine) integer and find XOR between every two words in the dictionary( ofcourse after converting them to integer) and probably store it in a new file.

Since I am new to python and because of large file sizes, the program is getting hung every now and then.

```
import os
dictionary = open("/usr/share/dict/words","r")
'''a = os.path.getsize("/usr/share/dict/words")
c = fo.read(a)'''
words = dictionary.readlines()

foo = open("word_integer.txt", "a")


for word in words:
    foo.write(word)
    foo.write("\t")
    int_word = int(word.encode('hex'), 16)
    '''print int_word'''
    foo.write(str(int_word))
    foo.write("\n")

foo.close()
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "XORing" words. How are you defining the result of the XOR of two **characters** (not bytes)? What should happen when the words are of different lengths?

Comment: @AaronHall It is Python 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:56) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Hmm... I did not think of this condition at all. I am trying to decrypt a one time pad cipher text. All I know is, cipher texts c1= 4ADD55BA941FE954 and c2=5AC643BE8504E35E
(eight bytes each, presented in hex) and they are encrypted using same key.Another information I have is they are encryption of english words. So I trying to XOR all words in the dictionary and see whether it matches with XOR of c1 and C2

Comment: I don't understand. What is the word being XOR'd with? What does that have to do with figuring out the plain text? It sounds like you have unknown words `W1` and `W2`, and a common key `K`, and you are given that `W1 ^ K = C1`, `W2 ^ K = C2`; is that right?

Comment: I solved it, I now have one problem...Reducing the complexity of the program. :( @KarlKnechtel and yes you are right. That is what the brute force attack is for. I love the mathematical simplicity over programming complexity. Thanks a ton to AaronHall as I am inspired by that logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need a method to convert your string to an int, I'll make one up (since what you're doing isn't working for me at all, maybe you mean to encode as unicode?):

```
def word_to_int(word):
    return sum(ord(i) for i in word.strip())
```

Next, we need to process the files. The following works in Python 2.7 onward, (in 2.6, just nest two separate with blocks, or use `contextlib.nested`:

```
with open("/usr/share/dict/words","rU") as dictionary: 
    with open("word_integer.txt", "a") as foo:
        while dictionary:
            try:
                w1, w2 = next(dictionary), next(dictionary)
                foo.write(str(word_to_int(w1) ^ word_to_int(w2)))
            except StopIteration:
                print("We've run out of words!")
                break
```

Comment: @Just this code will run? or should I add it with my code? I am not understanding.

When I try to run your code alone, it says syntax error and points at "as" in the 
with (open("/usr/share/dict/words","rU") as dictionary,

Comment: @user2888239 This should work as a drop-in replacement for your code above. Remember to use the context manager `with` to open files, it automatically handles closing them for you if you get an error.

Comment: This is how it looks like now, but no luck. I guess I dont know how to use it import os def word_to_int(word): return sum(ord(i for i in word)) from contextlib import contextmanager @contextmanager with (open("/usr/share/dict/words","rU") as dictionary, open("word_integer2.txt", "a") as foo): while dictionary: try: w1, w2 = next(dictionary), next(dictionary) foo.write(word_to_int(w1) ^ word_to_int(w2)) except StopIteration: print('We've run out of words!')

Comment: Let me see if I have what you want straight: open a file with a bunch of words, pull out two words at a time, process them to integers (what are the exact specifications here?), `xor` them, and then append that number to another file? I've made a couple of bug-fixes, but you need to try it again, and give me the error if you see one.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work for me. You're likely running into efficiency issues because you are calling `readlines()` on the entire file which pulls it all into memory at once.

This solution loops through the file line by line for each line and computes the xor.

```
f = open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r')                                          

pairwise_xors = {}                                                              

def str_to_int(w):                                                              
    return int(w.encode('hex'), 16)                                             

while True:                                                                     
    line1 = f.readline().strip()                                                
    g = open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r')                                      
    line2 = g.readline().strip()                                                

    if line1 and line2:                                                         
        pairwise_xors[(line1, line2)] = (str_to_int(line1) ^ str_to_int(line2)) 
    else:                                                                       
        g.close()                                                               
        break                                                                   

f.close()
```

Comment: But here, If I am right, isn't it writing back on the /usr/share/dict/words again in 7th line inside while loop? I can change it to some other file name if the logic I have understood is true.

Comment: The code didnt work, may be because it is not writing anywhere anything

Comment: You should use the context manager, and you need to learn how to use next on iterators.

Comment: This is how it looks like now, but no luck. I guess I dont know how to use it

import os


def word_to_int(word):
    return sum(ord(i for i in word))

from contextlib import contextmanager
@contextmanager
with (open("/usr/share/dict/words","rU") as dictionary, 
      open("word_integer2.txt", "a") as foo):
    while dictionary:
        try:
            w1, w2 = next(dictionary), next(dictionary)
            foo.write(word_to_int(w1) ^ word_to_int(w2))
        except StopIteration:
            print('We've run out of words!')